# Is &= guaranteed to behave like hypothetical &&= operator?

Tags: c++, logical-operators

sometimes I would like to do

```
bool success= true;
success &&= dosmthing1();
success &&= dosmthing2();
success &&= dosmthing3();
if (success)
```

Lets ignore that I could be using exceptions...
my question is is it guaranteed by C++ standard that `&=` will behave like nonexisting `&&=` for my use case?
...

EDIT: do smthing-s return bool

Comment: How can anything behave like something that doesn't exist? Not a real question.

Comment: @EJP Sorry, but I'd really doubt that anyone would have any problems imagining how this hypothetical `&&=` would behave if existent, apart from ambiguity regarding short-circuiting, but that may very well be inquired from the OP (who probably didn't think about short-circuiting at all). Not a real close-vote.

Comment: @ChristianRau I know about SCEval, but tbh I wasnt thinkning about it when asking this Q

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That depends on how you expect `&&=` to work. If you want `x &&= y();` to be equivalent to `x = x && y();`, then no, because in this expression `y()` is not called if `x` starts out as false, but in `x &= y();` it will be.

If you don't expect it to be short-circuiting and all your expression really have type `bool` (not something convertible to `bool`, like pointers, integers, or user-defined objects), it works. That's a lot of restrictions though.

Comment: The short-circuiting requirement is the critical one.  If `doSomething1()` returns false, `doSomething2` and `doSomething3` should not be called (I imagine).

Comment: @JamesKanze sometimes I need to call all functions sometimes I don't

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl If you need to call all functions, then you can't use `&&`, regardless.  The whole point of `&&` is that it short circuits, stopping at the first argument which returns false.

Comment: @JamesKanze in that case i have check if rv== false set success = false but yes you are right in this form it is not usable

Comment: so just to make it clear it is impossible by standard that if bool a is true and bool b is true that after a&=b a is false ?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl How would this be possible? Ok, the answer could have been improved by some references to integral promotion rules and int-bool-conversions.

Answer (score 6):

No, & is a bitwise and, && is boolean and. If dosmthing* returns something other than 1 or 0, the results will be different.

Comment: Makes no difference for booleans. But it's true that if the dosmething functions don't return bool, it might make a difference.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Why not? It surely does. Booleans are not 1-bit values.

Comment: Conceptually, they are. As far as bitwise arithmetic is concerned, they are.

Comment: @SebastianRedl In reality, they can't be, C++ has no "true" 1-bit boolean type. The implementation would be so that this **does** matter.

Comment: No, it still doesn't. Since every `true` will be converted to `1` and every `false` to `0`, the result of bitwise and is the same as if you do a logical and on the original booleans. The results only differ if one of the inputs is not, in fact, a boolean.

Comment: That is, the bool occupies more than 1 bit in memory, but the language only ever concerns itself with 1 bit. The others are just padding and ignored.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Since we don't know what type dosmthing returns, & and && are not the same. If dosmthing1 returns an integer value 2, && will evaluate as true, while & will promote the boolean to 1 and result in false.

Comment: As I said in my first comment, if the dosmething functions don't return bool, there is a difference.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl In that case it boils down to &= not short-circuiting.

Comment: @zennehoy tnx, that is what I wanted to know, aka is compiler allowed to represent bool by "char that has at least one bit set to 1" and then &= on two true-s might return 0(false).

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl *"is compiler allowed to represent bool by "char that has at least one bit set to 1""* - The compiler is allowed to represent `bool`s in whatever way it sees fit (it might even represent `true` by a 64bit value with all 0s and `false` by all 1s), but that's completely irrelevant. What counts is how `bool`s are converted to `int`s (and vice-versa) and that is guaranteed by standard, since bitwise operators don't work on `bool`s at all, they're converted to `int` beforehand...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl ...In the same way `double d = 1.0 & 0.0;` is guranteed to be 0.0, no matter what the floating point representation is, since `&` doesn't work on doubles at all.

Answer (score 4):

No; it isn't short-circuiting.

```
bool x = false;
x &= (cout << "You shouldn't see me!");
```

Comment: Even if it was short circuiting, the bitwise operation is still different from the logical one.

Comment: @H2CO3 If both of the arguments have type `bool`, then the only difference between `&` and `&&` is the short circuiting.  (This is why, for example, we don't need a `^^` operator.  Since exclusive or can never short circuit, there's no need for a short circuiting operator.)

Comment: @JamesKanze True. Except that at times, it would be a handy shortcut for contextually-converted-to-bool-and-not-equal.

Answer (score 4):

They are completely different.  In this case, the short
circuiting of `&&` seems important: if `dosmthing1()` returns
false, `dosmthing2` and `dosmthing3` would not be called if you
use `&&`.  They will be called if you use `&`.

In this particular case, why not just write:

```
success = dosmthing1()
       && dosmthing2()
       && dosmthing3();
```

This seems just as clear (at least formatted like this), and
avoids any need for `&&=`.